# Starting a headless Pi X session on a remote X server

Tags: xorg

I have a networked Pi downstairs with no attached monitor which I would like to connect to from upstairs on my laptop running an X server. Vnc is not a viable solution. I can `ssh -Y` into the Pi, which starts X on my laptop on request and starts X applications individually, but I would ideally like to run the window manager on the laptop as if I had entered startx.

Running startx tries starting X which fails since presumably X is already running.

```
X.Org X Server 1.20.11
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: linux Raspbian
Current Operating System: Linux luxonis 6.1.21-v8+ #1642 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr  3 17:24:16 BST 2023 aarch64
Kernel command line: coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=1 snd_bcm2835.enable_headphones=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_headphones=1 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=1 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=0  smsc95xx.macaddr=DC:A6:32:B1:20:9E vc_mem.mem_base=0x3eb00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x3ff00000  console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=43567a26-02 rootfstype=ext4 fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles
Build Date: 30 March 2023  01:46:14PM
xorg-server 2:1.20.11-1+rpt3+deb11u6 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/home/pi/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Apr 28 10:25:23 2023
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) parse_vt_settings: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (Permission denied)
(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/pi/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console.
```

Comment: Have you looked at `Xnest :1` or `Xephyr :1` over ssh which will open a window on your laptop to be 
 the screen and run a server in it. You can then start a `DISPLAY=:1 ... windowmanager`.